# Particle number ZERO

Tags: particles

Why is the first particle numbered as zero?

[image]

Comment: Probably cause array indexes start from 0 in Python

Comment: Is there something you want to do with the particles?

Comment: Its because array indices start with 0 in almost all programming languages. Its an offset to a particular memory address and the first item lies at offset 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because in several programming languages certain variables like for example "arrays" and "list" start off with zero as the starting number for the 1st item in the variables that go with that method. With that being said, if you were to script something that combines the use of a variable with the starting point as zero with something that loops like "while" or "do", you'd have to make sure to add a + or - 1 to ensure that your indexing doesn't mess up.

As is, there are several things that start off with zero like RGB color pickers, you'll see 0 - 255 or the max limits for say 32bit integers in the negative and positive you'll have -2147483648 to 2147483647 with zero as the starting point.

Hope that helps.